# Inheriting specific attributes with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, diamond-problem

I've been asked to make a program which has a base class, two derived children classes from it, and then another one which is derived from both children. The assignment asks me to inherit half the attributes from one child and the rest from the other one. (Hope this makes sense to you).
These attributes are not specific of the children, but of the base class. This is my code:

```
# include <iostream>

class Base {
    protected:
        int _var1;
        int _var2;
        int _var3;
        int _var4;

    public:

        Base() : _var1(10), _var2(20), _var3(30), _var4(40) {}
        virtual ~Base() {};

        int getVar1() const { return this->_var1; }
        int getVar2() const { return this->_var2; }
        int getVar3() const { return this->_var3; }
        int getVar4() const { return this->_var4; }
};

class Child1 : public virtual Base {
    public:
        Child1() { _var1 = 100; _var2 = 200; _var3 = 300; _var4 = 400;}
        virtual ~Child1() {}
};

class Child2 : public virtual Base {
    public:
        Child2() { _var1 = 500; _var2 = 600; _var3 = 700; _var4 = 800;}
        virtual ~Child2() {}
};

class GrandChild : public Child1, public Child2 {
    public:
        GrandChild() {}
        virtual ~GrandChild() {}
};

int main() {
    Child1      c;
    Child2      d;
    GrandChild  g;

    std::cout << c.getVar1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << d.getVar1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << g.getVar1() << std::endl;
}
```

With this code, g instance automatically inherits the attributes from Child2, but I want to pick which attributes it inherits from which class, e.g. _var1 from Child1 and _var3 from Child2.
Is that even possible?
Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: its unclear what the effect of picking from which `Child` the `Grandchild` inherits the members should be. `Base` is a virtual base, hence `Grandchild` has only a single `Base` subobject, and it does not matter whether that comes via `Child1` or `Child2`. How would you determine if `_var1` is inherited via `Child1` or `Child2` ? Are you taking about the initialization in the constructors perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stripped the unrelated parts off your code (every thing public, and no need to declare the virtual destructor again):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    Base() : var1(10),var2(20) {}
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

struct Child1 : virtual Base {
    Child1() { var1 = 100; var2 = 200; }
};

struct Child2 : virtual Base {
    Child2() { var1 = 500; var2 = 600;}
};

struct GrandChild : Child1, Child2 {
    GrandChild() {}
};

int main() {
    Child1 c;
    Child2 d;
    GrandChild  g;
    std::cout << c.var1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << d.var1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << g.var1 << std::endl;
}
```

It produces the [same output](https://godbolt.org/z/64Mr76Y4o):

```
100
500
500
```

This is because, the `Grandchild` constructor is equivalent to:

```
GrandChild() : Base(),Child1(),Child2() {}
```

A virtual base is always initialized by the most derived class. Then the `Child1` and `Child2` subobjects are initialized by calling their constructor. They are called in this order, because thats the order here `struct GrandChild : Child1, Child2`.

Thats why you see `500` on the last line of output. First, the `Base` constructor initializes `var1` to `10`. Next the `Child1` constructor assigns `100`. And eventually the `Child2` constructor assigns `500`.

You cannot selectively inherit only some members. I suppose what you want is to let `Child1` assign `100` to `var1` and `Child2` assign `600` to `var2`. Note that initialization of this members already happened when `GrandChild` called the constructor of `Base`. Because `Base` is a virtual base class and `GrandChild` is the most derived class, neither `Child1` nor `Child2` have any buisness in initializing the members  `var1` and `var2` of `GrandChild`.

You can however, write constructors that assign only some of the inherited members:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    Base() : var1(10),var2(20) {}
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

struct Child1 : virtual Base {
    Child1() { var1 = 100; }
};

struct Child2 : virtual Base {
    Child2() { var2 = 600;}
};

struct GrandChild : Child1, Child2 {
    GrandChild() : Base(),Child1(),Child2() {}
};

int main() {
    GrandChild  g;
    std::cout << g.var1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << g.var2 << std::endl;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/evesnxvxo):

```
100
600
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) It is a school assignment and it states "Its attributes and member functions will be picked from either one of its parent classes". That's why I thought I could pick the specific attribute value from each child class. What seems to work is to overwrite the value inherited by GrandChild in the constructor

Comment: @Mikel thats unclear wording. I can only guess what they mean, and I guess its about: for `GrandChild` its doesnt matter whether it inherits `Base` members via `Child1` or `Child2`. If you like you can consider them coming from `Child1` or from `Child2`, it does not make a difference